# Am new but i need help in pod install my pod file also attached

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/core":

In Podfile:

Firebase/core

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/core`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `14.3` on target `Spacechat` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Please help as I need to finish this task fast.

My podfile:

## #platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Spacechat' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'Appirater'

## #Firebase

pod 'Firebase/core'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Database'

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

end

Comment: Hi Tami! Welcome to SO! Please don't include phrases like 'need fast answer'. It almost always has the opposite effect of what it intends. Also, please consider thinking about what's really important to solve the question and then format it accordingly (including a concise title), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10449:

Pod spec/subspec names are case-sensitive. It should be `Firebase/Core`.

Also, not required, but recommended:
`Firebase/Core` is no longer recommended usage. Instead, directly specify the needed Firebase libraries. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods.

So an even better solution is to delete the line since it is redundant with `Firebase/Analytics`